# Did Wahi stop coming or will it continue till the end?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, prophet-isa, belief, sahih-muslim, end-times

There is a hadith in Sahih Muslim which says that Allah will send Wahy to Jesus (pbuh) on his return. It is in Kitab-ul-Fitn or in Signs of End Times

What I believed previously is that Wahy is closed forever after Muhammad (pbuh).

Ahmadis use this hadith to justify the continuation of Wahy.

Please clarify whether this hadith is Sahih or Hassan or Da`if and what's its interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

Prophet Jesus PBUH came before prophet Mohammed PBUH. Even if you believe that the Wahi does stop short after Prophet Mohamed, it does not apply to those Prophets that came before him and are still to come down (Just Prophet Jesus that SOME scholars say he would come back).

There are 2 hadiths that some scholars take the ruling that there is no Wahi after the prophet:

> روى مسلم في صحيحه عن أنس -رضي الله عنه- قال: قال أبو بكر- رضي الله عنه- لعمر- رضي الله عنه-: انطلق بنا إلى أم أيمن نزورها كما كان رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم يزورها، فلما انتهيا إليها بكت، فقالا لها: ما يبكيك! ما عند الله خير لرسوله صلى الله عليه وسلم، فقالت: ما أبكي أن لا أكون أعلم أن ما عند الله خير لرسوله صلى الله عليه وسلم، ولكن أبكي أن الوحي قد انقطع من السماء، فهيجتهما على البكاء، فجعلا يبكيان معها.

Translating to: It was narrated that Omar said: We went to visit mother of Ayman like the prophet PBUH used to and when we got to her she started crying. We asked why, what Allah has in store for the prophet PBUH is much better, she said I don't cry because of it but for that the Wahi has been cut off from the sky (Allah), and they all started crying.

> صحيح البخاري أن عمر بن الخطاب رضي الله عنه قال: إن أناساً كانوا يؤخذون بالوحي في عهد رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم، وإن الوحي قد انقطع، وإنما نأخذكم الآن بما ظهر لنا من أعمالكم، فمن أظهر لنا خيراً أمناه وقربناه، وليس لنا من سريرته شيء، الله يحاسبه في سريرته، ومن أظهر لنا سوءا لم نأمنه ولم نصدقه، وإن قال إن سريرته حسنة.

Translating to: Umar Ben Alkhatab said: People used to take the wahi from the prophet PBUH, and the wahi has been cut off and that now we take the face value of your actions. Those who do good will be safe and close to us and we don't know what his intentions are, Allah will account for his intentions. Those who do bad will not be safe and we won't believe them, even if they say they have good intentions.

Allah knows best.

Answer (score -2):

there is a huge debate about this, many scholars didn't believe in the return of masih (I find their claim to be more logical and believable).
but anyway.

that hadith is sahih in terms of degree. and that makes a huge contradiction in the story of (masih and dajjal and mahdi). which i personally find fake. because every hadith contradicts with the other and with the quran in some places.